# Updated php session variable not updated unless click "refresh"

Tags: php, session, refresh

I have a website based on PHP/MySQL. Each form (POST method) send back variable that I save in SESSION variables each time the form is sent, using a general code in the header of the file:

```
session_start(); foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
if ($key != "submit") {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) $$key = $value;
```

The code is working properly (no error, variables correctly saved in the SESSION). In the form itself, each field has a reference to the SESSION variable, so that when the user comes back to the form, the previously selected variable from the SESSION is recalled, for instance:

```
<input type="text" name="fmElement" id="fmElement" size="5" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo @$fmElement; ?>">
```

($_POST['fmElement'] is saved in a SESSION variable $_SESSION['fmElement'], quickly after saved in the variable $fmElement)

I have a button called "restart", which simply recall the page (NOT a "go back" javascript; I truly recall the page), and allow the user to modify the values enter in the form, and then submit again their updated request. My main issue is that, although the SESSION variables are correctly updated, it will NOT show the latest changes in the SESSION variables, but the one saved before. However, when I force the browser to refresh the page, the field fmElement is then updated!

Here is an example to make it clearer:
a) the user select "K" as a first element (this is about chemistry => K = potassium).
b) The user click OK and get the information about "K".
c) Then he wants to modify this and click "restart".
d) Then, he select "Pb" (lead) and click OK (again).
e) The form correctly take into account of this change and show the results for "Pb".
f) HOWEVER, and here is the bug... when he click a second time on "restart", then the browser will send back "K" (and not "Pb") in the fmElement field... WTF?!? (apologize for this awkward expression).
g) Only when the user force to refresh the page, then, the field fmElement correctly show "Pb", proving that the SESSION variable $_SESSION['fmElement'] has been correctly updated with the second request (point d).

I already tried the following, but none of these work...
1) Force refreshing the page by sending also a hidden "refresh" variable and force the browser to refresh with a javascript (in between ...), like...

```
    if (@$_POST['refresh'] == "1") echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.reload();</script>";
```

2) Force the browser NOT to save in cache with a meta like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

I could send you the full original code, but this will take in total >500 lines... Please, could someone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Julien

Comment: The problem seems to be your "recall" button then. Add a simple text output to your form with a timestamp. If the recall button does not update that, it's indeed a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I tried preventing caching and all the other things. The only way I ended up solving it was to use a GET request instead of a POST. Alternatively, I have recently solved a similar problem by performing a PHP page refresh when you get back onto the page. Add a query parameter onto the url when they are being returned to the form (this may solve the problem, as may break caching because a different page) and then if that query string exists do a `header("Location: $url")` with $url set to the form page's location, without the query string.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. First, I try indeed to avoid the GET method, as I can have many variables to send back (>10) and POST is more appropriate. I tried your proposition, and this did not changed. However, I should precise that I was working "offline" on my computer (Mac OS 10.6 / Safari) using my Apache and MySQL server with the program MAMP (equivalent to EasyPHP on PC). I just tried to upload my files on my server on the Internet, and now (this is weird) the problem disappeared! I guess the issue was related to the way the SESSION in MAMP are handled by Safari on my Mac...

Comment: @Julien Yes, it is likely to do with the fact that there is much heavier caching involved in the offline environment on pc's and macs, but that is a total guess. Glad you got it sorted